# Support of Video in different browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, video

i have a task to Upload video and play in different browser. i have tried playing a .Mp4 video on different browser
i have tried implementing the iframe like

```
 <iframe id="frame1" runat="server" visible="false" style="height: 222px; width: 482px;">
                </iframe>
```

and tried implementing it src at runtime as:

```
 frame1.Visible = true;
 frame1.Attributes.Add("src", objLessionsInfo.VideoPath.ToString());
```

It works at `chrome`. but not in `firefox` and `IE` 
I also tried implemeting the video tag of HTML5 as

```
<video controls="controls" tabindex="5" class="Video">
     <source src="Videos/2.webm" type="video/webm" >
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
     </video>
```

the same works at `Chrome` but not in `Firefox` and `IE` as `.mp4` works on `chrome` but `firefox` doesn't support. i have tried with `.webm` format it plays at firefox.

i am confuse with the concept of how to make a video support to a different browser or how to structure this task.
whether should i check browser and play a video for that particular browser ( in this case i have to upload a video in different browser)
or is there any universal plugin that can play a video in all browser
need help on it. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You have extra quotes in your source elements, they are not valid HTML and will be ignored.

Comment: @robertc Sir basically i wish to know the logic of how to structure the video display in different browser.

Comment: @robertc sir what code to use to change src of video during runtime??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a HTML5 video plug-in, like

```
Mediaelementjs.com
videojs.com
```

those plug-ins are automatically taken care of your browser compatibilities. ".mp4" is the good enough. If you don't have other video extentions(.ogg or .webm), plug-ins will automatically convert it to FLASH object.

Comment: thanks sir its working in Firefox and Chrome but still shows the problem in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Video stops just after start.

Comment: I have not faced any kind of issues like that. In IE browsers I can see the FLASH version of the video.

Comment: Use JavaScript to set the video SRC on runtime, like... you have an ID in your video tag, in JS try this, $("#VIDEO-ID").attr("src","PATH"); or document.getElementById("VIDEO-ID").src="PATH";